# API SOAP: Method retrieve, combine 6 or more filter conditions using 'OR' LogicalOperator

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, soap, triggered-send

I got 4 filter conditions Response to a soap Retrieve call using 'OR' LogicalOperator.

```
    <Filter xsi:type="ComplexFilterPart">
       <LeftOperand xsi:type="ComplexFilterPart">
       <LeftOperand xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
        <Property>CustomerKey</Property>
        <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
        <Value>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxEmail123</Value>
        </LeftOperand>
        <LogicalOperator>OR</LogicalOperator>
        <RightOperand xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
           <Property>CustomerKey</Property>
           <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
           <Value>xxxxxxxxxxxxxEmail45</Value>
        </RightOperand>     
   </LeftOperand>  

  <RightOperand xsi:type="ComplexFilterPart">   
  <RightOperand xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
        <Property>CustomerKey</Property>
        <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
        <Value>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxEmail78</Value>    
      </RightOperand>

    <LogicalOperator>OR</LogicalOperator>
   <LeftOperand xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
        <Property>CustomerKey</Property>
        <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
        <Value>xxxxxxxxxxxxEmail987</Value>
     </LeftOperand>     
  </RightOperand> 

</Filter>
```

In this way I have applied 4 Filter conditions and i got Response successfully From Exact Target, But i have 6 more values using  'OR' LogicalOperator Conditions like above code. how can i apply 6 more Conditions in SOAP RETRIEVE METHOD.

Comment: Have you tried simply adding them using the same pattern? Did you get any errors?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I tried same pattern, i din't get any error. but response not showing from Exact target